# Flask flash message tends to show &#39; code when used alert

Tags: python, html, flask, encoding, flash-message

[image]

As you can see, alert message created by flash function in flask always shows the ascii code.

I tried like,

```
@app.route("/test")
def test():
    message = "hello world"
    flash(message)
    return render_template("TestPage.html")
```

or

```
@app.route("/test")
def test():
    message = "hello world".encode("utf-8", "ignore")
    flash(message)
    return render_template("TestPage.html")
```

Python version on my pc is 2.7.
I also tried passing the string without assigning a variable but doesn't work.

How can I remove that ' code in my alert? and why does it happen?

Comment: Can you please share the html / js you use too?

Comment: Do you specifically need to have the message in a javascript alert?

Answer (score 1):

Oops, I just found an answer.
What I was printing out was not a message but an array of message.

My code that printed `&#39;` was like this.

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
       <script>
       alert('{{ messages }}');
       </script>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Now I changed it to print only one factor from the array.

```
{%- with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            <script>
            alert('{{ message }}');
            </script>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endwith -%}
```

Hope it helps!